# High charts when converted from html to canvas is blurry

Tags: canvas, highcharts, html2canvas

I am trying to convert html to canvas and use the canvas image to be exported in excel but while conversion itself the chart scale specifically comes blurred as shown below:-

[image: <code>rendered svg image</code>]

The Highchart is drawn in browser window and then the div element of that chart is used to convert to svg as below:-

```js
var sheet = document.getElementById('report' + i);
  $(sheet).css("height",sheet.scrollHeight);
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   
html2canvas(sheet, {
  
   onrendered: function (canvas) {
    lineChartImage = canvas.toDataURL().split(',')[1];
    var index = canvasArr.findIndex(function(item, i) {
      return item.SheetName === sheetName;
     });
    canvasArr[index]["CanvasImageString"]=lineChartImage; 
   }
   });
```

Comment: Have you considered Highcharts `export-data.js` module? Using it you can export data to CSV or Excel. Check here: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.csv, https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: Here i am trying to export multiple charts into excel sheet at same time. I draw all charts in browser then take array of div and iterate it through html2canvas and export it to  excel. I am not sure if export.js will work here, as it does for single chart only.

Comment: You can make it simply getting each csv (`chart.getCSV()`) and combining them all together. Check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qfa5o9s6/